# SQL Server 2012 create Xml with default values from xsd

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd

I have imported an xsd, containing 258 elements, into my SQL Server 2012 instance. It is mandatory that all 258 elements are present in the final xml. The issue I am having is that 246 of them will contain default values that are identified in the xsd and I do not how to construct my SQL to populate the xml with the default values.

The following is an example I created that illustrates my issue using a much smaller xsd:

```
DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestSchema
GO
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestSchema AS 
'<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="document">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
          <element minOccurs="0" name="field1" type="string" default="1" />
                <element name="field2" type="int" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>'
GO
declare @xml xml(TestSchema) = null
declare @reccount table(recordcount int not null)
insert into @reccount select 32
set @xml =
(
    select
        recordcount as field2
    from
        @reccount
    for xml
        PATH('document')
)
select @xml
```

The value of @xml is:

```
<document>
  <field2>32</field2>
</document>
```

Whereas i was expecting

```
<document>
  <field1>1</field1>
  <field2>32</field2>
</document>
```

Any ideas how I can generate the default value of field1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky for me I came across the answer fooling around with the select statement above. I just needed to add the field 'field1' with a '' for the data.

```
set @xml =
(
  select
    '' as field1,
    recordcount as field2
  from
    @reccount
  for xml
    PATH('document')
)
```

That did it.